# django filter with no arguments

Tags: django

I'm trying to write a custom filter that retrieves a list of objects which I then use in my template. So far I've got:

```
@register.filter
def get_my_object_list(user):
   return some list after processing
```

And in template:

```
{% for page in request.user|get_pages_with_no_menu %}
     Some rendering here.
{% endfor %}
```

Now this works fine, and this might sound silly, but I can't find the solution. I don't really need the user in that filter, so I would want to not have any parameters to it. Is this possible, and how do I call it from the template?

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are actually looking for is not a template filter, but an [assignment tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags). It allows you to assign a value to variable and then eg. iterate over it:

```
@register.assignment_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_pages_with_no_menu(context):
    # do some fancy stuff here
    return pages_with_no_menu
```

Then you can use it in the template like:

```
{% get_pages_with_no_menu as pages %}
{% for page in pages %}
     Some rendering here.
{% endfor %}
```